# Sony PMB causing failure to load Windows 7 Pro 64-bit normally or even Safe Mode

Tags: windows-7

After installing Sony's Picture Motion Browser on my desktop with Windows 7 Pro x64, it always goes to Startup Repair due to Windows 7 failing to start. This always happens after I try to install it. I've installed with all unnecessary programs closed and all disk drives and unnecessary usb ports empty. I don't exactly know what is causing the problem. Any ideas?

My desktop is an HP m8530f.
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01469325&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=3740333&lang=en
Only upgrades are an HD4350 and a 500W PSU.

EDIT: Windows 7 cannot start now. I'm currently running diagnostic tests from the BIOS.

EDIT: Here are the problem details.
Problem Signature:
Problem Event Name:    StartupRepairOffline
Problem Signature 01:  6.1.7600.16385
Problem Signature 02:  6.1.7600.16385
Problem Signature 03:  unknown
Problem Signature 04:  21201022
Problem Signature 05:  AutoFailover
Problem Signature 06:  8
Problem Signature 07:  CorruptFile
OS Version:            6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
Local ID:              1033

CONCLUSION: So, I think Sony PMB may have caused some sort of corruption in the system files. So if you have Windows 7 and plan on installing Sony PMB, find a Vista or XP machine to install on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did:

1. I found my Sony model and selected my operating system at esupport.sony.com
2. I installed new software. File was called "Lost the Original Software Installation Disc? Use the Picture Motion Browser Software Download Tool"
3. When prompted to restart computer, I selected **"No, I will restart later"**
4. I located file **pxhelp20.sys** in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\drivers *Computer > OS (C:) > Windows > SysWOW64 > drivers*
5. I deleted file **pxhelp20.sys** and removed it completely from trash can.
6. I restarted system successfully
7. I downloaded and installed update also from esupport.sony.com.  File was called "Picture Motion Browser Update (version 5.2)"
8. When prompted to restart computer, I selected **"No, I will restart later"**
9. I checked again for file **pxhelp20.sys** in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\drivers (it was not there, but had it been I would have deleted it again)
10. I restarted system successfully

Comment: I have PMB on an XP machine, but it appears as if your solution works for others.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem just a few days ago. I've managed to install PMB on my Windows 7 64-bit, by following instuctions on the following Sony website page...

http://support.sony-europe.com/dime/downloads/downloads.aspx?site=odw_en_GB&m=&f=PMB_64_installr

You need to download something which will allow you to install the original PMB version, then install two different updates.

But, now that I've done that, I can't link my camcorder to the computer. It doesn't seem to recognise it and I can't import any media files. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the software is made for x64 computers, that can cause issues.

Alternatively you could get it into [safe mode](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial61.html#windows7), uninstall the program and try booting up again. Because I don't think software would cause issues like this.

Comment: I definitely used the Windows 7 Pro x64 download. To access safe mode, would I have to go to the boot menu in my BIOS? I can give specifics of the error in a minute.